# How to make a circle with CSS3 around font-awesome icon?

Tags: css

I want to make a css3 circle around the icon that I want to draw. I am using the meyers reset before any other css: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

and I am unable to get the effect I want. This is my css:

```
i {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
border: 3px solid red;
}

<i>H</i>
```

If possible to make this responsive. What is the best way to do this? 
If possible, it would be nice to have the circle and text resize on its own as the user resizes

Comment: You ehmm, must set a border before.

Comment: The border is crunched up against the "H" and is not round like a circle.

Comment: The border got to be as big as the radius, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/koqbw6ep/1/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to make it responsive, then you shouldn't be using that border-radius:60px or whatver, for circle, border-radius:50% works perfect

Now to give your Font-Awesome icons a circular background effect, you can work it out this way:

```
.fa {background: #fcc;
padding: 1em;
text-align: center;
display: inline;
border-radius: 50%;}
```

but the problem here is, that the font-awesome icons aren't of equal width or height, so you may have issue of skewed circle (ellipse shape)

to prevent that, you can give some fix like:

```
 .fa {background: #fcc;
    padding: 1em;
    width:50px; /** fix width ***/
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 50px;  /** for vertical center - if needed **/
}
```

then using media query, you can alter these properties for different screen resolutions.

Comment: Yes, the ellipse shape is very problematic, so your saying a fixed width must be specified per icon and there is no "catch all"

Comment: That, width will be common for .fa class, it will get applied to all fontawesome icons.,

Comment: @Rolando Yes there is no way to make "global" solution with border-radius for different sizes of icons (for eg 20px 30px 40px etc). This is due to how border-radius work (it is border just with round corners). To make it round you have to make element square and there is no global way to make elements square. You have to specify width and height or use some hacks for eg: set line-height same as width etc... But there is other way you can add circle icon and create style on before using that icon and move it on icon using position absolute. it not pretty but it will work.

Comment: @Rolando if you active, then you may close this question by accepting the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

One take on this is *not* trying to match your padding / border / background, etc. on the size of the icon itself. By isolating the two, you can control the font size of the icon for responsive purposes along with the round, background appearance separately.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/wndrmnt/pen/NPOarV

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
  <!-- Facebook Icon -->
  <li class="list__item social">
    <a href="#facebook" class="list__icon list__icon_social"><i class="icon_social fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
  </li>
  <!-- Child Icon -->
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#facebook" class="list__icon list__icon_social"><i class="icon_social fa fa-child"></i></a>
  </li>
  <!-- PayPal Icon -->
  <li class="list__item">
    <a href="#facebook" class="list__icon list__icon_social"><i class="icon_social fa fa-cc-paypal"></i></a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Remove default list styling */
ul { 
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.list {}

.list__item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.list__icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.list__icon_social {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0066FF;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.icon_social {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to have 2 separate layers; one for the circle and another for the font awesome want to use. Here is the code:

```
.circle{
    border:2px solid orange;
    background-color:gray;
    border-radius:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
}

.fa {
    color:white;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="circle">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koqbw6ep/2/) but obviously the awesome fonts are not working there. BTW this is not a responsive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple theory to make a circle is you need to define value for height, width and radius must be equal. i.e. height: 50px, width:50px and border-radius:50px.